# pre-generated public/private RSA keys, unable to decrypt in C (works in python)

Tags: c, encryption, aes, rsa, public-key-encryption

I generated a public/private keypair with `openssl`:

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 1024
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in private.pem -outform DER -out private.der -nocrypt
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public.der
```

Now after that I created test code with Python, that was encrypting and deciphering strings. I took the example straight from `PyCrypto` documentation, encrypting:

```
string_to_encrypt = str(raw_input("Enter a string to encrypt: "))
print "Encrypting: %s" % string_to_encrypt

key = RSA.importKey(open('./public.der').read())
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(string_to_encrypt)
```

and decrypting:

```
dec_key = RSA.importKey(open('./private.der').read())
d_cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(dec_key)
dec_message = d_cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
```

Now this works as expected, and next I wanted to try deciphering same using `C`. I transfer the data via `socket` to the C application.. but now I'm unable to get the message back to clear text, even though the deciphering is not throwing errors.

Before I try to decipher the text, I print out the data to the screen, and the bytes match on both ends. The receiving function looks like this:

```
char* decrypt_packet(char* encrypted_buffer, int size) {
  FILE *keyfile = fopen("./private.pem", "r");
  RSA *rsa_pri = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey (keyfile, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  int rsa_private_len = RSA_size(rsa_pri);

  for(i; i < size;i++)
    printf("%02x:",(unsigned char)encrypted_buffer[i]);
  printf("\n");

  char * decrypt = (char*)malloc(rsa_private_len+1);
  memset(decrypt,0,rsa_private_len+1); //Zero the buffer for printing

  int res = RSA_private_decrypt(rsa_private_len, (unsigned char*)encrypted_buffer, (unsigned char*)decrypt, rsa_pri , RSA_NO_PADDING);
  if(res == -1) {

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    printf("ERROR: %s\n",ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(),NULL));
  }
  printf("size decrypt: %i\n", res);
  printf("decrypted: %s\n", decrypt);
  ....
```

The deciphering doesn't fail, but the output is garbage (here sending just a test string "hello world"):

```
received buffer:
82:9d:a7:f7:3c:d6:71:12:01:31:ba:c6:a2:90:94:90:fd:69:d3:fe:14:11:2f:af:a9:8a:25:99:55:d2:84:1f:dc:e3:5e:a9:be:7b:8a:ac:cd:38:76:a2:91:ec:24:da:06:c7:8d:67:c8:15:19:73:c8:57:ce:a5:87:f0:da:db:c2:6d:5b:55:a3:ba:7e:7d:ca:6b:02:23:fd:fe:cb:b4:04:53:e2:74:c3:91:77:ee:5f:7a:61:7a:87:a6:42:37:28:c6:9c:cb:6a:46:f4:c0:bd:fe:8a:92:da:86:53:3b:5c:e2:e3:79:81:2c:32:28:9c:4c:be:0a:fa:75:7b:b2:
size decrypt:    128
decrypted: dÕf`5åiõuy<òáµÛ~G=/
                          Ä
```

I have chosen to use `RSA_NO_PADDING`? I have no idea really if this is correct.

But if I use something else, the decrypt function complains: `RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:block type is not 02` or `RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP:oaep decoding error`

Am I correctly calling the `RSA_private_decrypt` function ? Could the problem be that I'm reading the `private.pem` file in C (in Python I was reading the `.der` file)?

One more thing came to mind. I used default `openssl` from Ubuntu to generate the keys, but my C application I'm linking against a downloaded and compiled source. The `Makefile` contains:

```
SOURCE_FILES = main.c client_handler.c
CC=gcc
$(CC) $(SOURCE_FILES) -o client_control_srv -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -I/home/jlumme/openssl-1.0.1f_x86/include
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You *definitely* need to use padding; leaving aside the fact that you had padding on the encryption so you must have it on the decryption, RSA is very insecure if not properly padded.

Comment: The lack of errors isn't very surprising when you don't use padding; RSA, like most ciphers, isn't *authenticated* and therefore doesn't know whether something decrypted correctly or not. The 128 bytes of output are basically just the padded blob (1024 bits). No idea why it's failing when you use PKCS1_OAEP to decrypt though; that *should* work unless the buffer got mangled somewhere.

By the way, why is this tagged "aes"?

Comment: @CBHacking, thanks for the comment. I'm 99% sure that the bytes transfered are the ones I encrypted (on both ends I print them one by one, I just skipped them here in the question to keep it simple).. No matter how I turn it around RSA_private_decrypt doesn't return success if I have either RSA_PKCS1_PADDING or RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING.. I even tried RSA_SSLV23_PADDING, but the problem persists :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my key generation was messed up.

I regenerated the keys:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey_priv.pem 1024
openssl rsa -in mykey_priv.pem -out mykey_publ.der -outform DER -pubout
```

and now it works with the same code. As CBHacking pointed out, I also needed to have padding set to `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`.